# $_GLOBAL variables set in config file are not being read correctly

Tags: php, global-variables, configuration-files

this might be a stupid question but I'm stuck here at this silly problem for the part 2 hours.

I have this function which checks if a particular config file's variable are not empty.
Here's the function :-

```
include 'inc.config.php';
function not_valid_settings()
{
    if((empty($_GLOBAL['id'])) || (empty($_GLOBAL['username'])) || empty($_GLOBAL['password']))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the config inc.config.php file:

```
$_GLOBAL=array();
$_GLOBAL['id'] = "asas";
$_GLOBAL['username'] = "asas";
$_GLOBAL['password'] = 'as';
```

Function Calling

```
include 'inc/inc.functions.php';
if(not_valid_settings())
{
    echo "Please enter correct entries in inc/inc.config.php";
    exit();
}
```

For some reason, I always get the Please enter correct details. Even if my `$_GLOBAL['username']='';`.
What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: I don't think `$_GLOBAL` does what you think it does, are you perhaps meaning `$GLOBALS`? (But really you shouldn't be using either.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually using `$_GLOBAL` as a variable for all global setting variables.

Comment: FWIW: don't include the "config" in the file that exposes the helper functions (it should be setup-by-global-mangling in the calling context)

Comment: The `$_` prefix is generally reserved for PHP superglobals.  Don't use the `$_` prefix unless you are accessing one of these.  Use something like `$SETTINGS` instead.

Comment: @cdhowie
I changed $_GLOBAL to $GLOBAL. It still doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: please read [http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$_GLOBAL` appears to be a PHP superglobal, but it is not -- there is no such superglobal in PHP.  As a result, this variable is not immediately accessible everywhere.  If you add `global $_GLOBAL;` as the first line if your function, your code should work:

```
function not_valid_settings()
{
    global $_GLOBAL;
```

Perhaps you meant to use `$GLOBALS` instead, though I would strongly advise against it.  Use a name like `$SETTINGS` instead, and don't forget to use `global $SETTINGS;` in functions where you need to access the settings object.

In general, you should avoid choosing variable names that start with `$_` unless they are PHP superglobals; this prefix implies a superglobal, while your variable is not.  This will create unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Thank you, I knew the concept of variable scope. But not sure my mind did not strike here.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$GLOBALS is what you mean to use, though this is not a good practice.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php